# Raspberry Pi's analog audio output in watts

Tags: audio, archlinux, audio-playback

Can some one tell me what is Raspberry Pis analog audio output capability? I would like to know how munch power 3.5 mm jack of raspberry pi can deliver in terms of watts. This will be helpful to decide what kind of speakers I can buy to use with Raspberry Pi along with many other audio devices. I am using Raspberry Pi model B with Arch Linux loaded in it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to purchase an amplifier. I took an old set of computer speakers and grabbed the amplifier out of it. It runs on 12v. This is a snippet from my tutorial on a Pi Arcade:

**Power Harness and Audio Amplifier**

> When you are ready to cram all the components of your Raspberry Pi
>   arcade into a MAME cabinet, you have the choice of suppling power to
>   pcb, pi and monitor separately or create a single power supply.
>
> I decided to create a single power supply with the following
>   components. I purchased a Wall Wart Power Supply - 12VDC 1.5AMP at a
>   local electronics store to be my main power source. I needed 12v to
>   power the monitor (a 7" reversible car monitor). Since the pi only
>   needs 5v, I used an old Tom Tom GPS car charger to drop the 12v to 5v.
>   In addition, I added a audio Amplifier (12v also), The pi's audio is
>   very low, so adding an Amplifier is needed. I found an old computer's
>   external speakers amplifier and used it.

[Pi Arcade tutorial with Audio Amplifier](http://phillystutorials.blogspot.com/2014/05/creating-raspberry-pi-arcade.html)

[image: Amplifier]

Comment: Thanks @Phil for the quick response. I don't want to connect the amplifier. I just want to use it as it is. I would like to know weather raspberry pi can drive 16 W speakers. What is the maximum wattage speakers it support with out any amplifier?

Comment: You are going to need an amplifier. Take a look at the `Wolfson Audio Card` - http://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/wolfson_pi

Answer (score 0):

I had to crank up the volume to max on the Pi and on my PC speakers to barely hear anything out of the Pi's builtin audio jack.

I purchased a [Syba SD-CM-UAUD USB Stereo Audio Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS) to get acceptable sound from the Pi (obviously when not using HDMI which works very well).  Looking on Amazon now I now see [this lower cost alternative](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007HISGRW) which has a comment saying someone was successfully using this unit on their Pi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, heatfanjohn. I would like to know maximum power of speakers raspberry pi can output. I could not find this in technical specifications anywhere.